# "Search engine" for classes

Tags: c#, reflection, lambda, queryover

I am trying to figure out a way to make it possible for users to search for a specific text or value in all parts of the domain.

For instance, I have these simplified classes:

```
public class Person
{
   public string FirstName {get; set;}
   public string LastName {get; set;}
   public string Password {get; set;} //just for this example it's a string
}

public class Company
{
   public string CompanyName {get; set;}
   public string PhoneNumber {get; set;}
}

public class Invoice
{
   public decimal Revenue {get; set;}
   public decimal TotalAmount {get; set;}
}
```

I want to be able to register per class which fields the user is able to search in. I don't want them to be able to search in the properties Password and Revenue. They can type an amount or some text in a box and it should check all instances of these classes if the text is found.

For example "51" might turn up as a TotalAmount when it's 51,99 but I might also turn up as part of a phone number.

So my question is, how do I go over all entities and retrieve the properties that are searchable with reflection? Or do I create a method with an expression[] that returns the properties?

With the result I want to use the property names to build a NHibernate QueryOver query dynamically for each specific entity and return the items it found per entity.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: So is the question how to create a list of properties, or how to write a dynamic query based on your entities? This is not really a simple problem so am guessing any simple answer wont really help

Comment: @TheGeneral point taken, I updated the text.

Answer (score 1):

Probably you can create an interface, for example ILookup to identify which entities will be available for searching. 
Later create an attribute to mark which fields will be available and then iterate over the assembly you have all entities and filter them with the interface. 
Something like this

```
var q = from t in Assembly.GetExecutingAssembly().GetTypes()
where t.IsClass && t.Namespace == nspace && t is ILookup
select t;
```

Answer (score 0):

First you should make a ViewModel since you don't want to expose you domain entities...Ever.

I think what you are looking for is the LINQ query .Contains()

```
objectList.Contains("query");
```

Comment: I know I shouldnt expose my domain entities. It was for the sake of simplicity. The contains method won't work. I need to visit the specified properties to compare the values.